# SQL tables relation

Tags: sql-server

- A member can take a policy and add members other that specific policy but "he" will be a main member/payer for it, ok.

  - Which means a Policy can have more than one members in it, taking into account that a main memmber may want to insure other member(s) in it.
  - So, I have a Member and policy table - now how do I link these 2 tables to avoid data redundance ?
  - ** a Member table for a main-member that will link to the policy table, and other table for additional members that will link the main-member?
  - ** Or 1 Member table to save all Policy members and link the policyId to it ?

The tricky part is that each member added on the policy get his own Insured amount, so the amount is not the same as Main-Member insured amount.
 - Do I keep the member's insured amount on the Member table or Policy table or just saparate table?

[Member] --> [Policy] 
**OR**
[Member] <-- [Policy] 
**OR**
[Member] <--[MemberPolicy]--> [Policy]

That's where Im stuck on right now. 
How would you solve this (my project) scenario ?

Any help will be appreciated

Apologies in advance if you deem my question as a bad topic.

Comment: Can the same Member be on multiple policies?

Comment: Yes, it's possible for that scenario, should they wish to take up another policy. Thanks

Comment: Then you have many-to-many relationship between Member and Policy and you do need a separate MemberPolicy table.

Comment: But how do i cater for extra members?
Example:
Member A - take a policy for R40K 
 then add additional members to it
   - Sister > R15K
   - Child > R5K
   - Spouse > R30K

Comment: You create separate fields in the "link" MemberPolicy" table to store member status ("main", "sister", etc.) and insured amount.  Obviously it's better to create a separate Status table and store just IDs in MemberPolicy.

Comment: Ok yes , they will have same policy number - that's perfectly make sense but ... remember, i need to have  full details for the additional members { sister, kid, mother } , their names, Idnumbers, etc...right?
So do I add such info on Member table as well and link it on "memberPolicy" ? >> info for additional members?

Comment: By mentioning that I need to add extra fields in the link table - you opened my eyes ,I didn't think of it - Thanks much appreciated